# Why can a real field have an imaginary saddlepoint?

Tags: path-integral

Suppose we have a functional integral of the form
$$
\int D\psi \exp\left( -S \right)
$$
over a real field $\psi$ with an action
$$
S=\int_r L(r,\psi(r))=\int_r \frac{1}{2}\psi(r)^2+i\psi(r) j(r).
$$
Now we could perform a saddle point analysis which would mean we search for the field configuration $\psi(r)$ which solves the Euler Lagrange equation
$$
\frac{\delta S}{\delta\psi(r)}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial\psi}=0.
$$
In this case this is the field configuration
$$
\psi(r)=-ij(r).
$$
Now my question: How can a real field $\psi(r)$ have an imaginary saddle point? I think it has something todo with the fact that using the Gaussian integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx \exp(-ax^2)=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{a}},
$$
a shift of integration into the complex plane $x\to x-ib/a$ to prove the relation
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx \exp(-ax^2+ibx)=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{a}}\exp(-b^2/a)
$$
is actually a variable transformation that makes the integration boundaries complex.

Comment: Well, the given action $S$ is complex. Is the question why $S$ is complex? If so consider to include some context.

Comment: The action is complex because it comes from a Hubbard Stratonovic decoupling of a term $\exp(-1/2 \int_r jAj)=\int D\psi \exp(\int_r 1/2 \psi A^{-1} \psi +\int_r i \psi j)$ where the $i$ on the right side in front of the $\psi j$ is due to the minus signs on the left in front of the $\int_r jAj$.

Comment: My confusion comes from the fact that the field $\psi$ is real and the saddle point apparently is not in the area of definition of $\psi$.

Comment: Right. So a real-valued classical description is absent, but the quantum theory is nevertheless well-defined. That happens.